# Access tabbar controller inside navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

So basically I have code that works when I display in a tab bar my RootViewController, but if I display it the right way, RootViewController inside MainTableViewController which is the UINavigationController class. For some reason though it doesn't work when inside the MainTableViewController.

```
MxFifthViewController *viewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", viewController);
int badgeValue = [viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue intValue];
badgeValue += 1;

viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", badgeValue];
[viewController downloadUrl:fileURL];
```

This code is in my RootViewController. I believe it has something to do with the self.tabBarController.viewControllers line, but can't figure out how to fix it. Basically when a user selects a row it will send the fileURL to the "Downloads" tab class (which is the last tabbar in my tab bar controller, and called "MxFifthViewController") and add a number badge to the "Downloads" tab.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. this: NSLog(@"%@", viewController); returns (null)

Comment: are you sure that you properly configured tabBarController?`self.tabBarController` is not nil?

Comment: Yeah it is (null), so how might I access it then? When I display just the rootviewcontroller class in the tabbar controller it works, but when the rootviewcontroller is displayed inside a navigation controller, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you display it in `navigationController` `tabBarController` property is `nil`, because there are no related `tabBarController`! You should find other way to get reference to that `tabBarController`. It works in first case, because when you display it in `tabBarController`, it set's your class [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarController) `tabBarController` to it's self. Is your `NavigationController` is inside `tabBarController`?